# there is an error when I try to make sql query to rename column name through asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

now, I working on asp.net. and I only put textbox and rename button on the web form. I want now to enter new name of one column (which is called skill1) in the text box then click rename button to rename this column 
please see my code below. there is an error in the last line. So, it is not work. I don't know what is the problem. please try to help me.

```
string conString = @"Data Source=FATTO-TOSH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Positions;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(conString);
    string sql = "EXEC sp_RENAME 'PositionsReq.skill1' ,  '"+name.Text+"', 'COLUMN'";
    c.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: in this line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ... the error is SqlException was unhandled by user code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("sys.sp_rename", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objname", coulmnName)
        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newname", name.Text)
        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: wow, really you are great.. now, the modification achieved only one time because when I change the name from skill1 to Sk for example. Then, I want to modify Sk to other name. the code doesnt work because it is initialize as column name is skill1 only.  do you have an idea how to generalize the code to work whatever the name of the column? thank you

Comment: @rosekhan you can send column name as parameter, like you set new name from `name.Text`

Comment: sorry but I try many time without any result. could you please tell me how to set this parameter. thanks

Comment: how you take the column name? if you get the column name from text box  called `column` then `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objname", column.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;`